# Uniform convergence of $1/(1+n^2x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

of course, we know that $\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$ converges uniformly on $[a,\infty] $ for a>0; for x>0.

I am having difficulty in proving for $x<0$. We have discontinuities at $x=1/k^2, \forall k\in Z^-.$ So for now I just wanted to prove it for $x<-1$

This is my attempt, if you could check it.

$$|1+n^2x|=|1-n^2|x||>n|1-n|x||$$so

$$\bigg|\frac{1}{1+n^2x}\bigg|<\bigg|\frac{1}{n(n|x|-1)}\bigg|<\bigg|\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\bigg| $$

and so the series converges uniformly for $x<-1$

Further, what do I do for $-1<x<0$ . Thank you

Comment: Let $a<0$, we can find some $K$ such that $a< - \frac 1 k^2$ for every $k \ge K$. Can you continue from there ?

Comment: @nicomezi what is this for?

Comment: That means that, for $n$ large enough, you can replace $|x|$ by $|a|$ in the last inequality and obtain a new upper bound which will be true on $(\infty,a]$. ($a <0$)

Comment: @nicomezi so does that mean my proof is right for x<-1? If it is then what you have just done makes complete sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for my (now deleted) comment. It seems correct to me. I was confused about your way of computing the bound.

Comment: oh that's great, so if I just do what you say, I can extend it to $ [-\infty,a]$ just instead  of $<−1/^2$, I can now use $a<-1/k$

Comment: @nicomezi, if you could see my previous comment

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If a<0 ,then there exist a K such that for all n>K ,a>-1/n^2.At -1/n^2 ,function tends to infinity.This is true for all n>K.So sequence is not convergent in sup norm .So it isn't uniformily convergent

Comment: What are you on about? The series is uniformly convergent in the set $[-\infty, \delta]\cup [\delta, \infty]$